# The number entered by the user is not being converted or interpreted as an integer in Go code

Tags: go

I am running this code in Visual studio code.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    min, max := 1, 100
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    secretNumber := rand.Intn(max-min) + min
    fmt.Println(secretNumber)

    fmt.Println("Guess a number between 1 and 100")
    fmt.Println("Please input your guess")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("An error occured while reading input. Please try again", err)
        return
    }

    input = strings.TrimSuffix(input, "\n")

    guess, err := strconv.Atoi(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Invalid input. Please enter an integer value")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Your guess is", guess)
}
```

I have copied this code from this link https://freshman.tech/golang-guess/ When I run this code on my system, after entering the number by hitting the enter key instead of printing the entered number my code is generating this output.

```
56
Guess a number between 1 and 100
Please input your guess
63
Invalid input. Please enter an integer value
```

Can anyone please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: `fmt.Printf("% x\n", input)`

Comment: I suspect this is related to your OS. I would suggest printing the error from `strconv.Atoi` so you can see why it is not able to parse the `input` variable as an integer. If you still can't solve the problem, you can share the error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows? I suspect your console is giving you `\r\n` at the end of each line, not just `\n`.

You can trim *all* whitespace from a string...

Instead of this:

```
input = strings.TrimSuffix(input, "\n")
```

Use this:

```
input = strings.TrimSpace(input)
```

This will trim space, including `\r` and `\n`, from both the beginning and end.